# How find a maximal region for log(Log)?

Tags: complex-analysis

Find maximal region $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ and some branch for $log$ (logarithm function) such that $log\circ Log$ is well defined where $Log$ is the principal branch of logarithm.

The immediately question: shows that there is a closed, piecewise smooth curve $\alpha$ on $\mathbb{C}-((-\infty,0]\cup\lbrace1\rbrace)$ such that
$$\int_{\alpha}\frac{1}{\zeta Log(\zeta)}d\zeta\ne 0$$